# How to put computers online in Apple Remote Desktop

Tags: macos, apple-remote-desktop

In Apple Remote Desktop I see my computers but they are offline. How can I put them on line so I can control the computer

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable remote desktop sharing on the target computers.

[image]

Apple has an excellent kickstart resource to enable this setting remotely.  See this [Apple Support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201710) and also if your network supports it, you can send a wake command if the network is active while the machine is sleeping. That last item won’t start a powered down machine or reach across routers, only machines oN the same subnet can be woken.